# Attribute circle-color always draws black circles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox, geojson

I am trying to display multiple circles on a mapbox-gl map. The color of the circles depends on the value of the `aqi` property. I have set interpolation of the color depending on that value. The problem is I am always getting black circles.

The circle color property:

```
'circle-color': [
    'interpolate',
    ['linear'],
    ['get', 'aqi'],
    0,        
    '#eee695',
    50,
    '#a5fc03',
    100,     
    '#dbfc03',
    200,
    '#fc1c03'  
],
```

The full function:

```
 map.on('load', () => {
                Axios.get('https://api.waqi.info/map/bounds/?latlng=41.03143,20.52421,42.20194,22.89056&token='+AQI_KEY).then(res=>{
                    const data = [];
                    res.data.data.map(station=>{
                        if(station.aqi!=='-'){
                            data.push(JSON.stringify({ "type": "Feature", "properties": {"aqi": station.aqi},
                            "geometry":
                            {
                                "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ station.lon, station.lat ]
                            }
                            }))
                        }
                    })
                    map.addSource('AQI', {
                        'type': 'geojson',
                        'data':
                        {
                            "type": "FeatureCollection",
                            "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "aqi": "aqi" } },
                            "features": data.map(JSON.parse)
                        }
                        });
                        map.addLayer(
                            {
                            'id': 'AQI-heat',
                            'type': 'circle',
                            'source': 'AQI',
                            'paint': {
                                'circle-radius': {
                                    'type': 'exponential',
                                    'stops': [[0, 70], [500, 70]]
                                },
                                'circle-opacity': {
                                    'type': 'exponential',
                                    'stops': [[-99, 0.0], [-50, 1.0]]
                                },
                                'circle-color': [
                                    'interpolate',
                                    ['linear'],
                                    ['get', 'aqi'],
                                    0,        
                                    '#eee695',
                                    50,
                                    '#a5fc03',
                                    100,     
                                    '#dbfc03',
                                    200,
                                    '#fc1c03'

                                ],
                                'circle-blur': 1
                
                            }
                            }
                        );
                })
        })
    }
```

Even tho I have set different colors for different values, I always just get black circles.

Answer (score 0):

Quick anwser:

replace: `["get", "property-name"]`

with: `["to-number", ["get", "property-name"]]`

For more information see: [mapbox docs](https://docs.mapbox.com/style-spec/reference/expressions/#type-system)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).